# I am trying to compile a bb recipe file in yocto. I am facing : make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop. erorr

Tags: yocto, rdkit

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/${PN}:"
SRCREV = "eb5499c2732fbf500c54fd5f1bded9e45793728e"
SRC_URI = "file://new.tar.gz"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
inherit autotoools
```

#this is the bb file
#after compiling i'm facing : make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop. erorr.

Answer (score 4):

`S` is probably incorrect. You need to set it to either `${WORKDIR}` or `${WORKDIR}/subir` where subdir is the only directory in your tarball.

`SRCREV` is a no-op (only used by the git fetcher (when one entry in `SRC_URI` starts with `git://`)).

`FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend` is a no-op here, the path is already used by default.